# WebView not loading Url because Canvas: trying to draw too large(...) bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, webview

I am trying to load urls from a recycler view news feed into an activity with a webview. Some load successfully but some of the url open the activity and then close it after trying to load giving me a `RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(106673760bytes) bitmap.`

I have read other posts about this particular error and they seem to sugest that this is beacuse images on the website I'm trying to load are too large for the canvas to draw so i tried adding settings to my webview like:

```
newsWebView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = false        
newsWebView.settings.blockNetworkImage = true
newsWebView.settings.blockNetworkLoads = true
```

without any success. I get this errors with urls like [this dailymail article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-8675649/Bindi-Irwin-Chandler-Powell-spotted-time-announcing-pregnancy.html)
Is there a way to load the url into the webview successfully, perhaps to scale the from the website down before loading?
How do i solve this?

This is a full copy of the exeption:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(106673760bytes) bitmap.
W/System.err:     at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:78)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.JavaBrowserViewRendererHelper.drawBitmapIntoCanvas(JavaBrowserViewRendererHelper.java:11)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.nativeOnDraw(Native Method)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.access$5400(AwContents.java:896)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents$AwViewMethodsImpl.onDraw(AwContents.java:53)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.onDraw(WebViewChromium.java:702)
        at android.webkit.WebView.onDraw(WebView.java:2824)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.draw(NestedScrollView.java:1998)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1277)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

in my activity i have this:

```
if (newsIntent.hasExtra("url")) {
            newsWebView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = false
            newsWebView.settings.blockNetworkImage = true
            newsWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = false
            newsWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            newsUrl = newsIntent.getStringExtra("url")!!
            newsWebView.loadUrl(newsUrl)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No news link", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start with catching the exception so the webview does not crash.

Comment: Please post such an url so we can test.

Comment: A url like this one [https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-8675649/Bindi-Irwin-Chandler-Powell-spotted-time-announcing-pregnancy.html] causes the exception.

Comment: Please post your url between ticks so we can see if you added a protocol like http:// or https://. Its unreadable now.

Comment: My mistake,  this is another example `https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8677435/America-never-felt-divided-dangerous-says-Caroline-Graham.html`